# How to align rating bar and a button in the middle of a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, ratingbar

[image]

I'm trying to combine the `RatingBar` and `Button` in one layout (either `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`).
The Ratingbar and Button always align on the top, and it has a long distance between the rating images with the button. (I tried to make them closer to each other, but the partical rating images covered by the button)

How can I align the rating bar and button in the middle of the layout?
I tried  layout_gravity` and it seems not to work for me.

#### test_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <RatingBar style="@style/customRatingBar"
               android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
               android:stepSize="0.5"
               android:numStars="5"
               android:rating="4.5"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/self_defined"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried using LinearLayout with weights then set gravity respectively (i.e right for the rating bar and left for the button)?

Comment: What do you want and what you have now? Sorry but it's not clear

Comment: @Eenvincible  I used linearlayout and weightSum to 2, rating bar and button set to 1 respectively, and orientation is horizontal, but the button overlaps with the fifth rating star...

Comment: assign android:torightof="@+id/btnSubmit" it will set them selves becuse if you see you xml it first reads you rating bar  and it have low height then the button if you give the right of first it read the height of button with respect to that it set the rating bar in center vertical

Answer (score 2):

Just add `android:layout_centerVertical=true`. For RatingBar do not forget to add the `minHeight` if you do `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

Try the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <RatingBar style="@style/customRatingBar"
               android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
               android:minHeight="40dp"
               android:stepSize="0.5"
               android:numStars="5"
               android:rating="4.5"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <Button android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/self_defined"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

to the parent layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:background="@color/white">
```

This should work whether you use a RelativeLayout or a horizontal LinearLayout.

Comment: `center_vertical` works for the button, now it aligns in the centre, but  both the rating bar and button sits in the middle...    i want the rating bar on the left side of the layout and the button on the right side, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <RatingBar 
        style="@style/customRatingBar"
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:stepSize="0.5"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="4.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:text="button"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/self_defined"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />
</FrameLayout >
```

Comment: your suggestion made the rating bar and button align in the middle and get very close to each other, do you know how to make the rating bar on the left side and the button on the right?